# How to handle digest authentication using Python and Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have a internal web interface in my company which works with digest authentication process. My task is to automate the login process and capture/retrieve required information from the web interface.

I have written below code to handle digest authentication using Python and created as a library in Robot Framework -

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
import urllib3
import  webbrowser

class DigestAuth():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def login(self,url):
        """COMMENTS HERE """

       urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
       r=requests.get(url, verify=False,auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'passcode'))
       return (r.status_code)
```

When I run the above code, the status code returned is 200. With this status code I am confident that my code is able to login to the application. However,I would like to automate this login process - **Open the url in a browser, complete login process (digest authentication) and perform required actions**. Is there a way where Selenium can be used to complete my task?

Please advice as necessary.